# When Deploying CDK to AWS via Docker, bash: cdk: command not found

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cdk

Present are two files, `Dockerfile.infra` and `docker-compose-infra.yml`. Firstly, `docker-compose-infra.yml` is built via the following command:

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose-infra.yml build
```

This results in no errors and finishes as expected.

The problem arises when trying to deploy this to AWS. The following command:

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose-infra.yml run cdk
```

Produces this error:

```
bash: cdk: command not found
```

This appears to be triggered when the `docker-compose-infra.yml` attempts to run the `cdk deploy` bash command.

The command should run because within the `Dockerfile.infra` build, cdk is installed via `npm install -g aws-cdk-lib`.

Dockerfile.infra file:

```
FROM node:16-slim

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN npm install -g aws-cdk-lib  \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # install Python
    python3-pip \
    # install Poetry via curl
    curl \
    && curl -k https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - \
    && apt-get remove curl -y \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock /
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev

WORKDIR /app/
COPY app.py cdk.json cdk.context.json /app/
COPY stacks/ /app/stacks/
```

docker-compose-infra.yml:

```
version: "3"
    services:
      cdk:
        command: bash -c "cdk deploy --require-approval never --all --parameters my-app-${ENVIRONMENT}-service:MyServiceImageTag=${IMAGE_TAG}"
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.infra
        environment:
          - AWS_PROFILE=${AWS_PROFILE}
          - ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
          - DEPLOY_ACCOUNT=${DEPLOY_ACCOUNT}
        volumes:
          - ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `aws-cdk` not `aws-cdk-lib`

```
RUN npm install -g aws-cdk \
```

This might be a bit confusing because `aws-cdk-lib` is also the name of the required Python dependency when writing Python CDK apps *and* a valid npm package.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Well spotted!